# PyCharm builtin code inspection vs flake8

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Does anyone have any experience with PyCharm builtin code inspection vs other code inspections like flake8 or Pylint?

Are there any advantages using flake8 or Pylint instead of using the builtin PyCharm Code inspection?

Comment: Why not both? You can always run `flake8` or `pylint` in the CI.

Comment: @PavelKarateev why both? What flake8 do what PyCharm builtin code inspection does not do? What extra features does it have in compare to PyCharm?

Comment: Apparently some linters like pylint can be more strict than the built-in PyCharm inspections, so they can serve as an additional tool if needed, but I don't have a specific example. Source: https://pavelkarateev.com/posts/2017/08/13/linters/